# XML Relationship Transform Algorithm

Tags: xml, ms-word, wordml, xml-dsig

I'm trying to validate a MS Word *.docx file with digital signature. In order to do validation, i have to calculate digest of referenced nodes and to check if it is same as one given in the signature (sig1.xml). I can't find info about how ti implement relationship transformation in order to calculate that digest.

the part of signature XML (sig1.xml) is as follows:

```
<Object Id="idPackageObject" xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature">
<Manifest><Reference URI="/_rels/.rels?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml">
<Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/RelationshipTransform">    
<mdssi:RelationshipReference SourceId="rId1"/></Transform>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/></Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>1vWU/YTF/7t6ZjnE44gAFTbZvvA=</DigestValue>....(next ref node ....)..
<Reference URI="/word/document.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>s2yQEJrQSfC0YoRe1hvm+IGBpJQ=</DigestValue></Reference>.....More Reference Nodes.....
```

/_rels/.rels file himself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
<Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/>
<Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/>
<Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
<Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/digital-signature/origin" Target="_xmlsignatures/origin.sigs"/>
</Relationships>
```

So i need to calculate SHA1 of /_rels/.rels, but before calculation i must apply relationship transform and C14N.

When i'm calculating digest of node with no relationship transform(of this node, for example:)

```
<Reference URI="/word/document.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"> 
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>s2yQEJrQSfC0YoRe1hvm+IGBpJQ=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
```

everything is fine, just doing SHA1 of referred URI(/word/document.xml in this case) gives me same hash as one given int the signature  node. But when it comes to node with relationship transform - calculations never gives same value as stated in the signature.

My Question in general is where to find info about this relationship transform and how to implement it ?

Thanks,

Georgi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main source of information on transforms, and relationship transforms in this case, can be found in ECMA's "*Office Open XML File Formats — Open Packaging Conventions*" paper. Link [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/activities/Office%20Open%20XML%20Formats/Draft%20ECMA-376%203rd%20edition,%20March%202011/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%202%20-%20Open%20Packaging%20Conventions.pdf).

The section of importance is 13.2.4.24.

Relationship Transform should create a copy of the .rels file, in this case "/_rels/.rels" and remove all *Relationship* nodes that don't match with *SourceId*. This file is what is eventually hashed and creates the digest.

> The package implementer shall remove all Relationship elements that do not have either an **Id value
>   that matches any SourceId value** or a Type value that matches any SourceType value, among the
>   SourceId and SourceType values specified in the transform definition.

Under step 3, "Prepare for canonicalization" it also states:

> The package implementer shall add a **TargetMode** attribute with its **default value**, if this optional
>   attribute is missing from the Relationship element

Because we are creating a relationship between files in the same package, we have the value of "*Internal*". You need to add this attribute before you hash it.

So after the transform and c14n, you should have:

```
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Target="word/document.xml" TargetMode="Internal" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument"></Relationship></Relationships>
```

**NOTE:** If you are using a unix system, be aware of linebreaks, the OPC uses CRLF not LF.